# What is wrong with setState?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

Flutter `setState` is a built-in state management approach listed in the Flutter official documentation along with a list of other libraries for state management
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Why are there so many state management alternatives to Flutter native `setState`  such `RiverPod`, `GetX`, `BloC`, `Redux`...? What is so bad with `setState` that motivates so many state management libraries to come into existence.

This is to the point that Flutter itself is endorsing those libraries by putting them on their official documentation.

Does it all come down to just performance? If so, do we have actual performance data that has proven that `setState` is very bad?

Comment: I think *so many state management alternatives to Flutter native setState* to reduce the boilerplate codes and simplicity.

Comment: setState is intended for a data change in the current widget to inform the framework to repaint that widget.  It's not meant for action at a distance, which the other frameworks are more adept at.

Answer (score 1):

- Why are there so many state management alternatives?

  The Flutter team did not endorsed a solution in the beginning and the community started to roll their own giving birth to the many options we have now

---

- Does it all come down to just performance?

  Not really you could get bad/good performance with `setState` or any other solution if used carelessly. Other state management solutions do permit more granularity regarding when to rebuild the UI or sections of it, but what they do make better is how convenient is to apply those optimizations or even default to some of them (eg: how Bloc or Riverpod do not rebuild the UI if the emitted states are the same).

There is nothing inherently wrong with `setState` and many parts of flutter use it .I prefer it for [ephemeral](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app) state (as explained by the flutter team) , not app state as it ties a little bit too much your app state with the UI and widget lifecycle.

You can certainly do a whole app using only `setState` but other options like provider(which is mostly just Inherited Widgets simplified), riverpod, or bloc decouple the UI from the "App state" or business logic. They make it easier to segregate behavior from UI and test it. A great example of [simple state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) is in the official docs or even creating a new project using the skeleton template `flutter create sample -t skeleton` which are guidelines by the flutter team and I agree that are very good defaults.